# Custom layout not used on submenu items when using actionLayout attribute

Tags: android

Following the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) about Android's menus, I was able to set a custom layout for one of my action bar's items (see item `alwaysThere`). For another item however, it won't show the custom version but always the standard text (see 'subMenuItem'). The difference between these two items is that the 2nd one is inside of a nested submenu.

```
<menu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app    ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <item
        android:id      ="@+id/alwaysThere"
        android:title   ="Always there"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/customlayout" />

  <item
        android:title="Root"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_people_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
                  android:id     ="@+id/subMenuItem"
                  android:title  ="Submenu item"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/customlayout" />
[...]
```

**Here's the result:**

[image]

versus

[image]

I have alternatively tried to inflate the layout manually and use `setActionView()` when creating the options menu. Same result: working for the root item but not for items in the submenu, even if explicitly calling `expandActionView()`.

What do I have to do to make the submenu entries also use the custom layout?

Comment: you can use `PopupWindow` for that

Comment: Any references, examples or more details?

Comment: Just wondering if this here is what answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490999/can-i-use-a-actionlayout-on-the-overflow-menu-of-android-support-v7-widget-toolb/35732788 - if it's in a submenu, it's not an action and thus no action view will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PopupWindow`. Follow these steps.

Create menu file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item
        android:id="@+id/action_menu"
        android:icon="@drawable/menu"
        android:title=""
        app:showAsAction="always">
 </item>

</menu>
```

Then `displayPopupWindow` inside like this `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_menu:
            displayPopupWindow(findViewById(R.id.action_menu));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Create pop-up window:

```
private void displayPopupWindow(View view) {
    PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(this);
            View layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_popup_menu_layout, null);
            popup.setContentView(layout);
            popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popup.showAsDropDown(view, 0, 0);
            popup.setFocusable(true);
    popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this would use my `customLayout` for the entries in the popup menu. Also, while it is nice to have this code, what is your answer to my question? Are you saying that custom layouts *cannot* be used directly and the only way to get them is to not use the standard behaviour and instead show a non-standard popup?

Comment: @Krumelur **AFAIK** i have same situation in my previous project I'm not able add custom layout in inside menu item so i have use **`PopupWindow`**

Comment: I'm still not seeing how this would solve my problem of custom *items*. I don't want a custom layout for the popup but for individual items displayed inside of it.

Comment: @Krumelur inside `custom_popup_menu_layout` you can make layout of your item as you want